# How to conditionally send emails Drupal 8 Webform

Tags: 8, webforms

I am trying to figure out how to do the following; based on a submitted value change the email behavior:

1. If (field 'send' value == no) then don't send the email
2. If (field 'member' value == yes) then change the email message

If I can find out how to do #1 above I could use that to achieve #2, in fact I suspect they have the same answer. I am looking for a hook but perhaps that is just me being stuck in D7 style of doing things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest dev release of Webform 8.x-5.x supports conditional emails and handlers.

[image: Conditions tab]

Comment: I can't keep up with the rapid pace at which you are improving this module!

Comment: can we send the mail for different user based on the field values ? If the values is empty , it should send to admin email ID, if not then it will be send to another user. Is it possible ?

Comment: @logeshvaran the question is very interesting but I think you need to ask a question yourself in a separate post

Comment: The short answer is webform email handlers support email routing based on selected options (ie select menu, radios, & checkboxes)